# What are the differences between two versions of Scanner?

Tags: java, input, console

What are the differences between these ways to read input from console?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
```

and

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
```

And what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The `Scanner` Constructors

As those calls stand, there is not much of a difference.

The first constructor of `Scanner` you used, `Scanner(Readable)`, takes as a parameter an object that represents an incoming sequence of **characters**, which can be read using a `CharBuffer`.

The second constructor of `Scanner` you used, `Scanner(InputStream)`, takes as a parameter an object that represents an incoming sequence of **bytes**.

It should be emphasized that bytes are not characters. Characters may be represented by different byte sequences depending on the character encoding, and may span more than a single byte each.

Internally, that second constructor immediately wraps the parameter with an `InputStreamReader` - which is a `Readable` supplying character data, thus it's almost the same as using the first constructor.

## `BufferedInputStream` vs `BufferedReader`

So the differences that remain are those between

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
```

and

```
new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
```

These have slight differences in the way they read in the data.

The first chain would be filling up a buffer of 8192 *characters* every time input is needed, getting each character from the underlying reader which would interpret it from the bytes of `System.in`.

The second chain would be filling up a buffer of 8192 *bytes* every time input is needed. So when the wrapping reader needs the next character, suppose that character is represented by two bytes in the input, and only one byte of that character is in the current buffer. The second byte will require another fill-up of the buffer.

I don't have empirical data, but I think that given that `Scanner` itself fills up a `CharBuffer` every time it needs data, the above subtle difference is going to be rather insignificant. In fact, I believe you can safely forgo using `BufferedReader` or `BufferedInputStream` and just feed either an `InputStreamReader` or `System.in` directly to the `Scanner`, and it will take care of the buffering.

## Specifying the character set of the input

There *would* be a difference if you needed to use a particular character set for your input. For example, if you wanted to ensure that the incoming stream of bytes is interpreted as `UTF-8`, you could use:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Otherwise, the input bytes would be interpreted in your default character set which may not necessarily be `UTF-8`.

There is another constructor for `Scanner` that also allows this with a plain `InputStream`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

This, too, will wrap `System.in` immediately with `InputStreamReader`, so not much of a difference there.

Comment: `Scanner` only has a buffer of 1024 characters, adding a `Buffered...` adds an underlying buffer of 8192 characters/bytes. So there is a difference if you are reading big amounts of data (e.g. files), but I don't think there is an advantage if you are reading smaller input (e.g. console input)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to answer these questions is to check the source of the actual implementation. You can download the source from here: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/ or just Google specific classes: "java.util.Scanner source".

In this case the matching source:

```
public Scanner(InputStream source) {
   this(new InputStreamReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}
```

You could achieve the same with this code piece:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(System.in))));
```